# login through email and phone number just like facebook in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-1.2

i am new in cakephp.i am developing an application in which there is a login page .. i have a database where the the user email with his number is also stored in the database ... now what i want  is in facebook you can login through your email and your phone number too .. so i want this functionality in my application too.. how can i do this in cakephp.how can i check the field in cake php that whether he has typed his phone number or email address.i dont want to add another textbox .. i want to have the same text box for email and phone number

Comment: You cannot tag it with 2.x and 1.x versions. Please chose only the major version you are actually using (2.x I assume).

Comment: @mark well it doesnot matter which version of cakephp .. i just want some simple explanation or code ... i can translate the code according to my requirments

Comment: "i just want some simple explanation or code" => if you wanted code (which probably you won't get as it doesnt work this way here) the version would be vital for a correct answer... So yes, the exact version you are using should always be mentioned.

Comment: ok can you give me some sort of explanation or some hint that how can i implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the multi column auth adapter:
https://github.com/ceeram/Authenticate/blob/master/Controller/Component/Auth/MultiColumnAuthenticate.php

by defining

```
'columns' => array('phone_number', 'email'),
```

Comment: i dont how can i add this line into my code ... here i have posted my question with code.. i would b very grad if you can help me on this one                                                                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121118/cakephp-multicolumn-authentication

Comment: There is even an example there: https://github.com/ceeram/Authenticate/blob/master/Controller/Component/Auth/MultiColumnAuthenticate.php#L8 come on

Comment: thankkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk you ... it is working fine .. thank you very much .